# immutable function that alter object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability

```
var brand = [{id:1,name:'samsung',price:1000},{id:1,name:'lg',price:2000}];
var changed = brand[0].price = 2000;
```

now samsung's price is equal to 2000 and it's assign to changed, but how to do it without mutate the brand variable?

or maybe I misunderstood immutable concept in redux? above code is actually ok?

Comment: Without context it's not clear what you're asking, i.e., there's nothing wrong with mutating the object in the context you've shown.

Comment: @DaveNewton - The context is the `redux` tag.

Comment: @OriDrori That is insufficient context. What's being *done* with `brand` is what determines context and whether or not immutability is a concern. In other words, without actual context, it may just be an X-Y problem.

Comment: @DaveNewton mutable, isn't that a clear context already?

Comment: @JessieEmerson No. Now, if you had said something like "I'm putting `brand` in the store, and need to update the store in a reducer" (which in the context of Redux is sufficient) that would be complete information. Without knowing *why* you're asking the question (e.g., there's nothing intrinsically wrong with mutating the object the way you have here) it's just a shoulder-shrugging, non-Redux, Plain Old JS question, which is trivially searchable.

Comment: This is unclear. You've tagged the question reactjs and redux, but neither is used in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Object#assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create a new object with the change you need. 
Use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the items that haven't changed from the original array, and [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to create a new array instead of changing the original.

```js
var brand = [{id:1,name:'samsung',price:1000},{id:1,name:'lg',price:2000}];

var index = 0; // changed element index

// creates a new object with the merge properties
var item = Object.assign({}, brand[index], { price: 2000 });

// creates a new array by combining the elements before the changed item, with the changed item, and the elements after the it in the right order
var changed = brand.slice(0, index) // the items before the changed item
  .concat(
    item, // the changed item
    brand.slice(index + 1) // the elements after the changed item
  );

console.log(changed);
console.log(brand); // brand haven't changed
```

If you transpile the code or browser compatibility is not an issue, you can use [array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [object spread](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html) syntax:

```js
const brand = [{id:1,name:'samsung',price:1000},{id:1,name:'lg',price:2000}];

const index = 0; // changed element index

const changed = [
  ...brand.slice(0, index), // the elements before the changed  item
  { ...brand[index], price: 2000 }, // the changed item
  ...brand.slice(index + 1) // the items after the changed items
];

console.log(changed);
console.log(brand); // brand haven't changed
```

Comment: [item] is es2015? never seen that syntax before. is push() still relevant in immutable programming? I saw concat more than push.

Comment: `Object.assign` is es2015. The rest is plain ES5.

Comment: Push mutates the array, while concat creates a new one.

Comment: concat is the same with push but did not mutates?

Comment: I don't understand this line `var changed = brand.slice(0, index).concat(item, brand.slice(index + 1));
` why brand.slice(index+1)?

Answer (score 0):

Found this nice article which clearly explains how we can make Objects and Arrays immutable.
http://wecodetheweb.com/2016/02/12/immutable-javascript-using-es6-and-beyond/